# How can I find out the "syntax group" of the current character?

Tags: vim

Sometimes when using vim I'd like to know why the syntax highlighting is coloring some text in a certain way. I'd like to be able to put my cursor on this text and enter some command to find out what syntax group it belongs to.

For example, I noticed that the first 50 characters of the first line in a `gitcommit` buffer (ie: a git commit message) was being highlighted in an odd color. I'd like to know what syntax group is being used for these characters so I can adjust my (custom) color scheme.

Comment: @glts Thanks. I searched for this question and couldn't find it, which is what lead me to come up with my own solution from reading the docs and reading `2html.vim`.

Answer (score 12):

The following command will output both the name of the syntax group, and the translated syntax group of the character the cursor is on:

```
:let s = synID(line('.'), col('.'), 1) | echo synIDattr(s, 'name') . ' -> ' . synIDattr(synIDtrans(s), 'name')
```

To make this more convenient it can be wrapped up in a custom command, function, or key binding.

How this works:

- `line('.')` and `col('.')` return the current position
- `synID(...)` returns a numeric syntax ID
- `synIDtrans(s)` translates `s` by following highlight links
- `synIDattr(s, 'name')` returns the name corresponding to the numeric syntax ID

This will output something like:

```
gitcommitSummary -> Statement
```

Comment: How to wrap this command up in a convenient custom command or ...  ?